# return a list consisiting of the elements from tuples

Tags: erlang

How does one return e.g. the first element of a tuple?

I would like to take a list of 2 element tuples and return the second element of each tuple as a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1> P = {adam,24,{july,29}}.
{adam,24,{july,29}}
2> element(1,P).
adam
3> element(3,P).
{july,29}
```

See also: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id2259804

Answer (score 2):

you could use lists:map (not so simple like lists comprehension though):

lists:map(fun({_,X}) -> X end, [{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}]).

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this one probably behaves best when dealing with bad data, which can justify the slightly more complex looking syntax.

Answer (score 1):

exactly what you've asked:
666> [element(2,X) || X <-  [{1,2},{3,4}]].
[2,4]

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted a little help understanding it, not just the code.

Comment: alJaree, to understand you can read http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, true, element/2 + comprehension will work. But the best way is to pattern match:

[ Var2 || {_Var1, Var2} <- [{1,2},{3,4}]]

Every pattern matching is superior to function call, due to code simplicity.

So, above what you have is list comprehension (double pipes inside the list). Before pipes (right hand side) there is generator, left side is a product.

General:

List = [ ReturnedValue = some_function(X) || X <- GeneratorList, X =/= Conditions ]

Comment: About comprehension in erlang doc: http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html